# Are questions about finding sites to get free <X> on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, public-beta

There may be applications that are able to organize free assets efficiently and with features but the majority are either plain websites or blogs.

I can allow that but since it is not possible to moderate what the community answers, you end up getting websites anyway which may be great so why not upvote them?

I think this adds to the "list of `<X>`" problem.

To add to this, I think the [free](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) tag should be blacklisted from use.

Examples:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/web-applications-to-find-free-icons
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/free-educational-video-tutorials
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7872/how-to-get-royalty-free-images-of-gadgets

Comment: can you provide some examples of these questions? I originally misunderstood what you were asking here..

Comment: @Jeff I updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These questions seem a bit "meta" to me.. a web app to *find other web apps*?

So I tend to agree, cut out the middle-man and just list the actual web apps themselves, not the places where they are aggregated.